# SQL Server 2008. How to partition parent/child tables together?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have data split other few tables as per 3d NF.

say `Parent (ID, ParentData)`, `Child (ID, ParentID, ChildData)`

`Parent` has `Date` field and I want to split the parent and all children by the `Date` (so all data which constitutes a particular date has to be separated in a partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than you might think, the phrase used for tables / indexes being placed on the same partition scheme can be referred to as 'partition aligned'.

- Create a single partition scheme, allocating your partitions onto the filegroups.
- Create a single partition function, accepting a date parameter.
- Create both tables, each creation has an additional clause at the end.

The caveat there is that both tables (Parent / Child) need to have that date column within their schema. The child record can not inhreit the parents partition - you could use a computed column and a few other tricks, but you basically need to ensure the child records contain an appropriate date as well.

```
ON your_partition_schem_name ( your_date_field )
```

Indexes can also be 'partition aligned' in the same way as the tables can.

Comment: to be honest i was mostly interested how to force a child into the same partition with the parent without adding date field. I am adding several millions records a day. it is already bloated. denormalising children with the date field doesnt make me feel anyhow better....

Comment: AFAIK - it can't really be forced, even with a computer column that has to be persisted and schema bound (more hassle than putting the date on). The pain you would experience by not having them partition aligned though is a powerful factor you should consider.

Comment: I totally agree. so this is why I am trying to find out how to align without denormalisation.. are you saying this is 100% not possible? (to align without adding Date to all children) ?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the date.